# Spring RestTemplate Post запрос

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rest

Как отправить 3 переменных из одной программы в другую?

Есть 3 переменных:

1. Integer (цифра 15)
2. Integer (цифра 15)
3. Integer (цифра 10)
4. String (строка в виде json)

Отправляю так:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("code1", 15);
map.put("code2", 10);
map.put("json", jsonString);

restTemplate.postForEntity(url, this.getRequest(), responseType, map);
```

Проблема в том, что на другой стороне все переменные null. Если из `map` убрать `json` то значение переменных норм.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CourtController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseDto setStatement(
            @RequestParam(value = "code1", defaultValue = "") Integer code1,
            @RequestParam(value = "code2", defaultValue = "") Integer code2,
            @RequestParam(value = "json", defaultValue = "") String json) {
            ***
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте принимать не параметрами, а объектом. Что-то вроде:

```
public ResponseDto setStatement(@RequestBody Map map) { ... }
```

Мне кажтеся дело в том, что вы передаете данные в виде `json` - объекта, а принимате в виде параметров. То есть, нарушаете стандарт `HTTP`. Рекомендую убрать `map` и гонять данные из сервиса в сервиса в виде некоторого объекта вашего класса. Так будет сохраняться явный контракт между сервисами.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Присвоил переменные к объекту и передал объект, с другой стороны получил объект.
`restTemplate.postForObject` и `@RequestBody` объект сделал